# XCode 6.3.2 View is not shown in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode6.3

I have a simple view controller that have a `UIImageview` as background view.I add it from storyboard. It is shown well before.

But,I open this project today and find that the `imageView` just disappear in **storyboard**.

[image]

I also notice that the imageview become gray in here

[image]

Thanks

The answer

**I setup this project in one size class but I see it in other.**

Comment: It seems to be hidden

Comment: i think you make it in another size class and you see it in another...check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the hidden view from the right panel (the one with Stars name), go to the attribute inspector and check if the view is installed in the current size class.
[image]

Comment: I did not change anything with this project for days. Is it a bug?

Comment: No , This functionality is use when you want to install or not a specific view in a specific size class, If you didn't play around with size classes, maybe you did accidentally. Get the silver lining, maybe you learnt something new. Size classes are a very powerful tool, the fact that you can install view or constraint independently from one to another is awesome.